# Why in: body parameter is showing muliple time in swagger.json file?

Tags: swagger, resteasy

> Structural error at paths./{id}/payment-methods/{paymoid}.get.parameters
> should NOT have duplicate items (items ## 0 and 1 are identical)
> i: 1
> j: 0
> Jump to line 80
> Semantic error at paths./{id}/payment-methods/{paymoid}.get.parameters
> Multiple body parameters are not allowed.
> Jump to line 80
> Semantic error at paths./{id}/payment-methods/{paymoid}.get.parameters.1
> Sibling parameters must have unique name + in values
> Jump to line 85

```yaml
'/{id}/payment-methods/{paymoid}':
    get:
      tags:
        - Customer Resource
      summary: Get customer payment method
      description: ''
      operationId: getPaymentMethods
      ***parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: false***
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/AccountPaymentMethodDetails'
        '400':
          description: Bad request
        '401':
          description: User unauthorized
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lFPu.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - rather than hyperlink renditions of text, paste the text into your post.  What is your answerable programming question?

Comment: Did you generate this API definition from code (e.g. using Springfox or Swagger Core)? If yes, post your source code with annotations.